# multiple json objects into a list

Tags: python, json

```
{"Id": 1,"product": "Mobile","price": 32889,"description": "Samsung"}
{"Id": 2,"product": "laptop","price": 52889,"description": "Dell"}
…
…
{"Id": 3,"product": "Mobile","price": 25889,"description": "Poco"}
```

Each line is a complete json object by itself and have multiple lines.  I am trying to put these objects into a list. Can someone help. 
I am new to Json .

Comment: initialize `list1 = []` and append josn object into list like `list1.append(jsonObject)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean here? Are these in a file or?

Comment: What is the expected output? just `list` of jsons (a.k.a. `dict`-like in python)

Answer (score 1):

If your json objects are individual separate objects, then;

```
j_obj1={"Id": 1,"product": "Mobile","price": 32889,"description": "Samsung"}
j_obj2={"Id": 2,"product": "laptop","price": 52889,"description": "Dell"}
# init list
my_j_list=[]
# add your objects to list
my_j_list.append(j_obj1)
my_j_list.append(j_obj2)
```

If your json objects are dynamic ,e.g. populating from user inputs

```
j_obj = <dynamic from outside>
my_j_list=[]
my_j_list.append(j_obj)
```

Python list works based on index and value, mean; above j_obj_1 gets append at index 0 and j_obj_2 gets append at index 1

To print your list

```
# to print glance of list
print my_j_list
# to print individual contents of list, or some operation
for j in my_j_list:
    print j
# to print element stored at index 1
print my_j_list[1]
```

Learn more about list at [Python-Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)